# How to import a column from an Excel file?

Tags: excel, database, matlab, import, nan

This is my excel file:
[image]

Here I read the entire column A of the Excel sheet named "Lazy_eight" but the problem is that I have different sheets in which the column A has a different number of elements. So, I want to import only the numbers without specifing the length of the column vector.
I use the function readmatrix with the following syntax in order to read the entire column:

```
p_time = readmatrix('Input_signals.xlsx','Sheet','Lazy_eight','Range','A:A')
```

I get this in matlab workspace:

[image]

So, I wish to give to the "readmatrix" function only the first element of the column I want to import but I want that it stops at the last element, without specifing the coordinate of the last element in order to avoid the NaN that you can see in the last image. I want to import only the numbers without the NaN value.
I cannot read the initial and the last element  (in this way: 'Range', 'A3: A13')  beacuse in every sheet the column A (as the other ones) has a different number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using the “rmmissing” function, that removes “NaN” values from an array.